# Quiero hacer una Lista de tipo char pero no puedo

Tags: java

No puedo crear una lista de tipo char en NetBeans, solo puedo crear de tipo String

Esto no funciona

```
public List<String> lista_s = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Esto tampoco

```
public List<char> lista_s = new ArrayList<char>();
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a S.O. en español. Te invito a hacer el recorrido y así ganarás tu primera medalla. Para poder ayudarte es necesario que muestres parte del código que ya tienes hecho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que debes utilizar objetos en vez de tipo de datos nativos dentro de los corchetes angulares `<>`, si quieres crear una lista de tipo `char` debes utilizar la clase envoltorio `Character`:

```
public List<Character> lista_char = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, ya está resuelto